# Wpf DataGrid cashes after update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have got MVVM Applikation. Now i need a Datagrid with a variable amount of columns and rows.
Initial populating the datagrid works fine, but the application crashes randomly when updating the datagrid with the following exception

> "An unhandled exception occured in the UI: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation >   might not execute.'."

The crash happends directly after calling drawDatagrid()

code in my xaml:

```
<DataGrid
                            MaxWidth="{Binding Width}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SizeQuantityTable}"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                            SelectionMode="Single"  SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                            MouseDown="DataGrid1_MouseClick"
                            MouseDoubleClick="AppointmentOnMouseDoubleClick"
                            CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                            CanUserResizeRows="False"
                            CanUserSortColumns="False"
                            CanUserAddRows="False"
                            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
                            GridLinesVisibility="All"
                            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"

                            />
```

The Code in the ViewModel for updating the Datagrid

```
private void drawDataGrid()
    {
        SizeQuantityTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dayColumn = new DataColumn();
        try
        {
            dayColumn.ColumnName = "Tag";
            SizeQuantityTable.Columns.Add(dayColumn);
            foreach (var line in CalenderWorkPlanLines)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
                column.ColumnName = line.Fullname;
                SizeQuantityTable.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < DaysOfMonth.Count(); i++)
            {

                    DataRow row = SizeQuantityTable.NewRow();
                    row[dayColumn] = DaysOfMonth[i];
                    int j = 1;
                    foreach (var line in CalenderWorkPlanLines)
                    {
                        var tmp = line.AppointmentsString.ToList();
                        row[SizeQuantityTable.Columns[j]] = line.AppointmentsString[i];
                        j++;
                    }
                    SizeQuantityTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        (System.Action)(() =>
                        {
                            RaisePropertyChanged("SizeQuantityTable");

                        }), null);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Loggers.StartUI.Error("Exception during population of SizeQuantityTable - WorkPlanAppointments" + "in CalenderWorkplanViewModel", ex);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there an update thread that would modify the CalendarWorkPlantLines collection? That modification, especially adds/removed will break the draw call if the draw call is context switched during enumeration.

Comment: CalendarWorkPlantLines are modified before every call of drawDataGrid. There is no thread that modifies the CalendarWorkPlantLines collection while executing drawDataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see any obvious coding errors in your `drawDataGrid` method, the `Exception` that you mentioned is caused because you cannot modify an item from a collection that is being  enumerated using the `Enumerator` class, which is what is used inside a `foreach` loop.

The fix is simple... once you have found the `foreach` loop where you are trying to modify the item, you can simply replace the `foreach` loop with a `for` loop. Here is a short example:

```
foreach (Person person in People)
{
    person = anotherPerson; // not allowed
}
```

Instead of the code above, use the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
{
    People[i] = anotherPerson; // allowed
}
```